# Can we use function as a return statement in javascript?

Tags: javascript, return

Well, is it possible to use function as return statement in outer function?

I want to use something like this:

```
function returnFunction(){
    // some magic (unknown for me) code here
}

// and here is just usual function
function calculateFunction(a,b){
    var result = a + b;
    returnFunction();
    showResult(result);
}
```

So, the function above should only calculate "a + b" but don't show it result  because "returnFunction" should play a role of native "return" statement in "calculateFunction".

I know that I can always do something like this:

```
function calculateFunction(a,b){
    var result = a + b;
    if( needReturnFunction() ) return;
    showResult(result); // won't run if above true
}
```

But my point is to actually simulate "return", replace it.

So, if it possible, what the "magic code" then?

Comment: You can use a function call as part of an expression in a `return` statement, but otherwise your question is nonsensical.

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to ask. How about you describe your *actual* problem, and we solve that?

Comment: a `throw new Error()` does something close to what you describe. Of course, you need to catch it somewhere otherwise it bubbles all the way up.

Comment: Not as shown: `return` can return *any* value, but `return` (the keyword) must be used in the given function to return *a* value. (Exceptions do not return values, although they do flow along call stacks and can be caught.)

Comment: There's no sort of code injection or macro system available. The `returnFunction()` will not have the ability to directly influence the flow of the caller unless, as you show, the caller uses its return value. Nor can it read local variables of the caller's environment.

Comment: Well, I guess you could create sort of a "Franken-function" by piecing together strings of functionality and giving them to the `Function` constructor or `eval`, but I really don't think that's what you should do.

Comment: This seems to violate 'causation' at the code level. Unique. Possible race condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can imagine something like that is if you `throw`

```
function returnFunction(){
    if (shouldReturn) throw 'return';
}

// and here is just usual function
function calculateFunction(a,b){
    var result = a + b;
    returnFunction();
    showResult(result); // won't run if above throws
}
```

But then you would have to always use `try`, `catch`:

```
try {
  calculateFunction(a, b);
}
catch (err) {
  // if error thrown is 'return' then ignore
  if (err !== 'return') throw err;
}
```

This is **definitely not** something nice to do. You should probably re-think your code.

Comment: Well, if throwing an exception is the "only way" then it is better to always use `if` statement like this `if( needReturnFunction() ) return;` instead of always catching an 'error'